# How to resize buttons and labels in Bootstrap according to screen size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a beginner in css and bootstrap. I am using stable version 2.3.2 of Bootstrap.

Note : The only css files I include in my project are (in same order) -

1. bootstrap.css
2. stickyfooter.css (for sticky footer at the bottom of page)
3. style.css (my custom overrides for some styling)
4. bootstrap-responsive.css

All the responsive features of Bootstrap framework work well except the `.btn` and `.label` class. 
They do not scale (smaller/larger) according to the screen size. Any alternate way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes!  Using the usual responsive class on a `<div>` and making a block level button inside it.

```
<div class="span2">
    <button class="btn btn-block">My Button</button>
</div>
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yK3a5/1/)

Comment: So I need to use `container-fluid` and `row-fluid` for this? And does these work in 2.3.2?

Comment: Nope, that's just my personal preference.  It's just the regular responsive stuff.

Comment: Kinda late in the game here for me. But this seems to only resize the widths of buttons, not actually make them smaller or larger like you do with  btn-sm or btn-lg.

Comment: Yeah, that's usually the intention. The heights on bootstrap buttons are good for mobile.  The normal is clickable, lg is very clickable, sm can be clicked but you might miss. I don't think there are any scale modifiers in bootstrap.